# big O calculation for loop with two conditions

Tags: big-o

The following is a code snippet for closest-pair-of-points from geeksforgeek.

As you can see in the comment, it says that function will be run at linear not O(n^2).

It is because the second loop can be run at constant time:

`for (int j = i+1; j < size && (strip[j].y - strip[i].y) < min; ++j)`

Here is my question:

For this loop, it will be run at n times anyway, unless "j" is not over size.

I know that it will not execute inside the loop for some "j",
but it's true that loop will be run "n" times anyway.

So when we are calculating big O notation,
do we need to only care about the case executing the inside loop?

If so, can you recommend any good reference explaining about this issue?

```
// A utility function to find the distance beween the closest points of
// strip of given size. All points in strip[] are sorted accordint to
// y coordinate. They all have an upper bound on minimum distance as d.
// Note that this method seems to be a O(n^2) method, but it's a O(n)
// method as the inner loop runs at most 6 times
float stripClosest(Point strip[], int size, float d)
{
    float min = d;  // Initialize the minimum distance as d

    qsort(strip, size, sizeof(Point), compareY);

    // Pick all points one by one and try the next points till the difference
    // between y coordinates is smaller than d.
    // This is a proven fact that this loop runs at most 6 times
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        for (int j = i+1; j < size && (strip[j].y - strip[i].y) < min; ++j)
            if (dist(strip[i],strip[j]) < min)
                min = dist(strip[i], strip[j]);

    return min;
}
```

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points/

Comment: It cannot be linear as `qsort` is `O(n log n)` in the average case

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: I assumed that was referring to the loop, but your reading is more likely correct.

Comment: @ScottHunter well, the method in the for loop would be incorrect if the points were not sorted, so you cannot ignore it.

Comment: I'm not saying you don't need to execute the sort, just that the O() remarks were only referring to the loop; as I also said, that is probably a mis-reading on my part, given that the question is about the loops.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any "issue": The inner loop runs in O(1), and it is executed n times, making the whole of the nested loop O(n).

As to *why* the inner loop in O(1), that is based on the claim in your code that "This is a proven fact that this loop runs at most 6 times"; you haven't provided nearly enough information for anyone to explain why it is so, much less refute the claim.

Comment: I mean, how could the inner loop run in O(1)?
I know, some "j" can't execute "dist" functions at all, but the loop runs (n-i) times anyway unless the condition, "j is lesser than size", is satisfied.
So the inner loop run (n-i) times, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the loop is `(strip[j].y - strip[i].y) < min`. The `j < size` condition is just to stop it going over the array bounds, but the other condition is what's important for the complexity. The loop will terminate whenever either condition is reached, so you only need to look at the one that creates the lower bound.

It's checking the vertical distance between the points. Each point is further away than the previous, so the distance is increasing. The number of iterations depends on when this distance reaches `min`, where `min <= d`.

This is the same as asking how many points can fit inside two `d` by `d` squares that are placed horizontally next to each other, given that no pair of points within a single square are closer than `d`.

This is a geometry question that is answered in the [linked page](http://people.csail.mit.edu/indyk/6.838-old/handouts/lec17.pdf) The answer turns out to be 8 (or 7 excluding a starting point), so there's at most 7 iterations of the loop, giving a complexity of `O(1)` for the inner loop, or `O(n)` for both loops.

*The comment says 6 iterations, but they say 7 elsewhere, so that's inconsistent, but what's important is that it's a constant.*